# Reduction to Diagonalization language to prove that Universal language is not REC

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I am having troubles in understanding why this proof is done like that.
Why do we need to make a reduction to Ld which isn't even in RE to disprove Lu being rec?

And why does the book (Automata Theory, Languages and computation by Hopcroft, Motwani, ullman) constructs a machine for Ld to get a contradiction?

[This is the machine that I dont understand at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0zy8.jpg)

Thanks everybody in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduction is not done **to** the diagonalization language, but **from** the diagonalization language. The difference is very important here.

The idea of reduction is that the fact that there is a reduction from $A$ to $B$, noted $A\leqslant B$, can be translated as:

> if we know how to solve $B$, then we know how to solve $A$.

Another interpretation could be:

> if we cannot solve $A$, then we cannot solve $B$.

The principle of such a reduction is the following: from an instance $x$ of the problem $A$, construct an instance $y$ of the problem $B$ such that $x\in A\Leftrightarrow y \in B$.

In the reduction in HMU, the proof gives a reduction from $L_d$ to $\overline{L_u}$. Since the book has previously proved that $L_d$ is not recursive (indeed, it is not even recursively enumerable), the reduction $L_d\leqslant \overline{L_u}$ proves that $\overline{L_u}$ is not recursive, hence $L_u$ is not recursive.

Comment: And why are we copying w twice? What's the sense in doing that? Thanks a lot anyways! I kinda got the point now

Comment: In $L_d$, you are asking if $w$ doesn't belong to the language of the Turing Machine of code $w$. In $\overline{L_u}$, the input is two words: the code $\langle M\rangle$ of a Turing Machine, and a word $w$, and you asks if $w\notin L(M)$. So $L_d$ is more or less $\overline{L_u}$ when using the same word twice ($w$ is the code $\langle M \rangle$ of a Turing Machine **and** the word that belongs or not to $L(M)$, hence the duplication).